# CCS unresolved symbols in linker or compiler causing errors

Tags: c, windows, compilation, linker, msp430

I am newbee c programmer so be patient.  I have a MSP430 C project in Code Composer Studio 7.3 using windows 7.  My project (USB) was working fine and then I tried to add more code to incorporate a SPI interface and everything went sideways.  I restored my original code but now have problems that weren't there before.  Seems to compile but has several unresolved symbols errors in the linker (I think).  I have searched/researched many answers to these types of problems on the forum and tried many things (over the past two days!!) and cannot resolve my problem.  Possibly I made things worse by copying library/functions directly into my project directory but still didn't seem to change anything. The errors are related to standard MSP430 functions, not my code. My project tree looks like:

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwkFT.jpg)

Errors from Console are:

[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfm1b.jpg)

From everything I have read it indicates that either I have a compiler library path problem or a linker file path problem.  Tried a lot of combinations to no avail.   Following are the compiler and linker path info:

[linker 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAxqu.jpg)

[linker 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKTzP.jpg)

If I look in my repository of library stuff downloaded from TI you can see that the dma.h and dma.c files which reference the error message lines in the files are there and I don't understand why the linker can't do its thing.

[dma file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYan.jpg)

In the linker under library files I noticed the original libmath.a file didn't point to anything so I found one and added it (not help).  Also the libc.a points to a section of 3 directories (different versions of a tool) which each have a different version of libc.a and I think I tried all of them.  See below for directories

[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIO0O.jpg)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

A CLUE POSSIBLY: CLUE? In my quest to solve my issues, I created a new CCs project and pasted my main.c file in and then went through a series of compiles solving the errors as the showed up. I was down to one error : can't open source file hal.h. I believe this is a file that was included with the usb example code I started with. After copying it into my project I am back to square on with all the errors listed above. To get here I only needed to point the compiler to driverlib to solve previous errors. The hal.h file seems to only include driverlib.h which is also referenced in my main function so why all the errors??

FIXED BUT WHY!!!
To solve this issue I imported the drivlib directory from the TI repo on my D drive into my project.  Now everything compiles.  Can anyone tell me why I had to do that given that I had path directives to look on my D drive??  Can it be related to search path length being too long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code/output. Copy & paste the text into your question.